# jQuery connect as dojo connect alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, frontend

i have a dojo code in this way

```
dojo.connect( window, "keypress", this, this.keypressHandler );
```

i want to achieve the same with jQuery, i tried getting information about jQuery connect but couldn't find much except in an answer in stack overflow mentioning this.

Is it feasible to replace $ with dojo and use the same alternative API,

if yes, please enlighten me in using jquery connect

else please suggest implementing same use case with jquery

Comment: the closest function i think your looking for is the `on` function

Comment: i am using jquery 1.6.x and found out 'on'  can be used from 1.7 only

Comment: bind is the 1.6 version echivalent

Comment: yup, thanks @madalinivascu ..used that